# GraphicsMagick: Dock is Blacked Out

Tags: c++, linux, imagemagick, screenshot, graphicsmagick

#### GraphicsMagick

I'm trying to do a screen capture with GraphicsMagick. For some reason, the dock is blacked out in the captured image with the following code:

```
#include <wand/wand_api.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  MagickWand *wand = NULL;
  wand = NewMagickWand();
  MagickReadImage(wand,"x:root");
  MagickWriteImage(wand,"screen_shot_graphicsmagick.jpg");
  if(wand){ DestroyMagickWand(wand); }
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot from GraphicsMagick]

#### ImageMagick

With ImageMagick, however, I was able to capture the screen without any noticeable problems with the following code, which is just a few added/modified lines:

```
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  MagickWandGenesis();
  MagickWand *wand = NULL;
  wand = NewMagickWand();
  MagickReadImage(wand,"x:root");
  MagickWriteImage(wand,"screen_shot_imagemagick.jpg");
  if(wand){ DestroyMagickWand(wand); }
  MagickWandTerminus();
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot from ImageMagick]

I'm running this on an Ubuntu 13.04 OS. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here or why GraphicsMagick is blacking out the dock?